# How to expand war in Spring Boot's embedded tomcat?

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, war

I have a war archive with a web application. I want to start that application within my Spring Boot application. I therefore followed the advice from [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374726/spring-boot-how-to-add-another-war-files-to-the-embedded-tomcat):

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainerFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

        @Override
        protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(Tomcat tomcat) {
            try {
                tomcat.addWebapp("blog", "/tmp/roller.war");

            } catch (ServletException ex) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to add webapp", ex);
            }
            return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
        }

    };
}
```

That works quite well, except the war doesn't get extracted:

> Unable to create the directory [/tmp/tomcat.9153500015669016883.8080/webapps/blog]

That's the layout of the tomcat working directory:

```
$ find /tmp/tomcat.9153500015669016883.8080/
/tmp/tomcat.9153500015669016883.8080/
/tmp/tomcat.9153500015669016883.8080/work
/tmp/tomcat.9153500015669016883.8080/work/Tomcat
/tmp/tomcat.9153500015669016883.8080/work/Tomcat/localhost
/tmp/tomcat.9153500015669016883.8080/work/Tomcat/localhost/blog
/tmp/tomcat.9153500015669016883.8080/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT
```

A [breakpoint in `ExpandWar.expand()`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/TOMCAT_8_0_0/java/org/apache/catalina/startup/ExpandWar.java#L119) reveils that it wants to create a directory in webapps/. This non existing webapps folder is taken from `Host.getAppBaseFile()` (which comes from the `ContextConfig.context`).

So for me it looks like something is weird configured and it should be expanded into work/Tomcat/localhost/blog. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this is not spring related, but expected behaviour of an embedded tomcat. I found [this related issue](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/Embedded-Tomcat-does-not-automatically-create-quot-webapps-quot-folder-td5051412.html):

> The user is expected to define a valid directory for a Host's appBase.

So simply creating the default appBase directory before deployment does the trick:

```
tomcat.getHost().getAppBaseFile().mkdir();
tomcat.addWebapp("blog", "/tmp/roller.war");
```