# How Can I Load External War Files at Runtime with Tomcat Embedded in Spring Boot App

Tags: maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I am trying to get a Spring Boot jar featuring an embedded Tomcat server to load an external war at runtime. I'm trying to do this using the technique shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374726/spring-boot-how-to-add-another-war-files-to-the-embedded-tomcat).

The container bean in the Spring Boot application:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainerFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(Tomcat tomcat) {
            try {
                Context context = tomcat.addWebapp(tomcat, "/first", "path/to/my.war");
                WebappLoader loader = new WebappLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
                context.setLoader(loader);
            } catch (ServletException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to add webapp", e);
            }
            return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
        }
    };
}
```

Maven Dependencies for the external war:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When i start the Spring Boot container app, the container bean locates the warfile and adds it to the classpath, but then throws a ClassNotFoundException:

```
2017-01-13 15:14:22.520  INFO 208 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/first]  : 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
2017-01-13 15:14:22.520  INFO 208 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/first]  : Marking servlet jsp as unavailable
2017-01-13 15:14:22.520 ERROR 208 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/first]  : Servlet [jsp] in web application [/first] threw load() exception

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1050) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4913) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5223) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_112]
```

I've tried including jars with org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet in the war. I've also tried using a Spring Boot war (application class extends SpringBootApplicationInitializer, packaging to war and giving the tomcat starter dependency a provided scope) which also gives the same error. Open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat-Jasper is missing. Depending on the version of the embedded Tomcat, that your Spring Boot uses add following dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
  <version>8.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

For Spring Boot 1.4.1.RELEASE it is version 8.5.5 ([Available versions of "tomcat-embed-jasper"](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper)).

To check if the library is present after adding the dependency to Maven, package your application. In the packaged application you will find it under

> \BOOT-INF\lib\tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.5.jar