# running external war file with embedded tomcat in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Current scenario:

I have spring boot application which was running in jboss. Now I tried to run it in production using its own embedded tomcat and it runs perfectly.

The problem:
There used to be another war file in the jboss deployments directory which is also needed. I followed Vojtech Ruzicka's reply from the link [Spring Boot: How to add another WAR files to the embedded tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374726/spring-boot-how-to-add-another-war-files-to-the-embedded-tomcat) to add the war file into my embedded tomcat.

The issue is that when i am adding the war file, it is giving me errors like

```
Failed to scan file [c:/Users/blahblah/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.6.1/hk2-Utils.jar
```

This is absurd as the file path is wrong. The correct path of the hk2-utils is

```
c:/Users/blahblah/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-utils/2.6.1/hk2-utils.jar
```

There are loads of other such files like asm.jar, asm-tree.jar etc which it is tyring to find under the same wrong folder

```
c:/Users/blahblah/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.6.1
```

I tried to put all the jars under the directory it is looking to find but still the error remains the same.

Note: I unjared the war file using jar -xvf blah.war. It has some very basic files such as

```
META-INF / MANIFEST.MF
WEB-INF/ web.xml, weblogic.xml
index.jsp (This has some very basic imports like java.lang.string and java.util.*)
```

So nothing complicated in the war file itself.

Any chance i can get rid of these errors or atleast make tomcat look at the right path for the jars? Any chance to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

They are just warnings. I was able to start both the main war file by adding some dependencies which were missing.